# HTML file does not seem to be running my PHP

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

I created the following xhtml code as to accept input then run it through a PHP file to then return said input:

"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>User Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Please enter user information</h2>
        <form action="display_user_info.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="address" name="address" required="required"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="city">City:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="city" name="city" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="state">State:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="state" name="state" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="zip">Zip code:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As well as this PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>User Information</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>User Information</h2>
        <?php
        // Process form data
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
            $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $phone = $_POST["phone"];
            $address = $_POST["address"];
            $city = $_POST["city"];
            $state = $_POST["state"];
            $zip = $_POST["zip"];

            // Display user information
            echo "<p><strong>Name:</strong> $first_name $last_name</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Phone:</strong> $phone</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>Address:</strong> $address</p>";
            echo "<p><strong>City, State, Zip:</strong> $city, $state, $zip</p>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have placed both files into a project folder and placed that folder in the "Htdocs" folder where Xammpp is installed. If I click on the html file and submit info it just displays the raw php code, if I try to type localhost into a browser I get an error that it is not found.

I made sure apache was running and that the files were in htdocs, I also created a test.php to see if aapache was running correctly.

Comment: `If I click on the html file`...that'll never work, because it only invokes the PHP interpreter if you run it through the webserver, rather than accessing directly through the filesystem. Check the XAMPP/Apache settings to ensure you've definitely put the files in the correct folder for it to serve them, check that Apache is running, and then try going to `http://localhost/yourHTMLfile.html` (with the correct HTML file name in there instead, obviously) in your browser.

Comment: This is not XHTML so I removed that tag. Also, not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go step by step to resolve this issue.
First, rename your HTML file to have a .php extension, such as index.php. This will tell the web server to process the PHP code inside the file.
Second, please open your web browser and type localhost/project/index.php in the address bar. This will request the file from the web server and execute the PHP script
Note that /project/ is an example of the directory you have placed your files into